# CURSOR vs. UPDATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

A company uses a SQL Server database to store information about its customers and its business transactions. A new area code has been introduced for your city. The area code 111 remains the same for telephone numbers with prefixes that are less than 500. The numbers with prefixes that are 500 and greater will be assigned an area code of 222. All telephone numbers in the Phone column in the Customers table are stored as char(12) strings of the following format, ‘999-999-9999’. i must make the appropriate changes to the Customers table

as quickly as possible using the least administrative effort. Which one should I use ?

a.

```
UPDATE Customers SET Phone = ‘222-‘ + SUBSTRING(Phone,5,8) 
FROM Customers WHERE SUBSTRING(Phone,1,3) = ‘111’ 
AND SUBSTRING(Phone,5,3) >= 500
```

b.

```
DECLARE PhoneCursor CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT Phone FROM Customers 
   WHERE SUBSTRING(Phone,1,3) = 111 
     AND SUBSTRING(Phone,5,3) >= 500 

OPEN PhoneCursor 
FETCH NEXT FROM PhoneCursor 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE Customers 
    SET Phone = ‘222’ + SUBSTRING(Phone,5,8) 
    WHERE CURRENT OF PhoneCursor 

    FETCH NEXT FROM PhoneCursor 
END 

CLOSE PhoneCursor 
DEALLOCATE PhoneCursor
```

Comment: **(a)** - if ever possible, ***avoid*** cursors, especially for simple set-based operations like an `UPDATE`

Comment: Yeah, but @marc_s the cursor can still be used to wrap a set based method for chunking up the data. If the dataset is too large you can sometimes get performance gains as well as avoid a scenario where you might have to rollback for several hours.

Comment: There are other questions that need to be answered before accurately answering this question.  For example, if there is a business requirement to not lock the DB for long periods, then *absolutely* build staged data and process the updates in batches, locking and releasing quickly.  Also, this question smells of homework.

Comment: Although there's a theoretical possibility that 5,000,000 rows may be updated, in reality it's highly unlikely that the full range of numbers is already in use - let alone at full density. Therefore, in the absense of any aggravating factors, I would expect **(a)** to complete in a few seconds at most - a short enough time unlikely to cause ill-effects elsewhere. The big question mark though is the unknown **aggravating factors**: Are there indexes, foreign keys, or (especially) triggers that could slow the job down? If so, batching could help, but its hardly "least administrative effort".

Comment: Addendum, my previous comment assumes the numbers are unique. Which in retrospect I suppose may not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big update will hold a transaction against the database for, potentially, a long time... locking things up and causing all kinds of havoc.

For this, I would recommend a cursor to spread that load out over a period of time.

I've also done a 'chunked' update... something like this:

```
DECLARE @Done bit = 0
WHILE @Done = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE TOP(10000)
        Customers SET Phone = ‘222-‘ + SUBSTRING(Phone,5,8) 
    FROM Customers WHERE SUBSTRING(Phone,1,3) = ‘111’ 
    AND SUBSTRING(Phone,5,3) >= 500 

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Done = 1
    END
END
```

Comment: Brettwgreen, are you saying that CURSOR would perform this operation quicker and with the least administrative effort than an UPDATE by itself would ?

Comment: It depends on how many rows... if this thing has millions of rows, the update may take a very long time and block a bunch of other operations in the meantime. That's where the CURSOR or chunked update would be better... If there's only a few thousand rows, go for the update.

Comment: Upvoting as this question is object *only when all known business constraints are stated*.  For example, we don't know if we can have a long running lock on the table.  *If we can*, then throw a very high transaction level on there and update in one statement.  Too many unknowns.

Comment: Actually, while the basic idea is beneficial, if you break up a big update into chunks, you should be aware that there's a roughly 5000 rows limit where SQL Server will convert row-level locks in a **lock escalation** to table-level locks. So if you break up your update into chunks - try to make those chunks **less than** 5000 rows to avoid that lock escalation!

Answer (score 1):

The cursor would be far slower in any large dataset, talk about hours vice seconds or milliseconds. What it will do is not lock up the database from other users for as long at any one time.

This is, why with a large dataset, the batch approach can be best.

In general I would try the set-based approach first and run it on off hours if need be. Then I would try the set-based approach which runs a batch of the records only if the set-based is too slow.

If you have to go the cursor running one record at time, then there is probably something massively wrong with your database design. Cursors are generally the approach of last resort. Do not use them for inserts/updates or deletes.

Comment: I would avoid blanket statements... use the right tool for the job. It may not be acceptable to lock a table up for hours. I have also documented a case where a cursor is orders of magnitude faster than a set-based operation: https://brettwgreen.wordpress.com/2012/10/17/sql-cursors-are-slow-except-when-they-arent/