# Update values of table using the values from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `table1` in SQL Server:

```
id    start    end     value        flag   main_name
----------------------------------------------------
 1      10     20.2    pending        T     abc
 2      22     11      pending        T     abc
 3      12.1   15      pending        F     abc
```

I have another table `table2`:

```
id    start    end     value   flag    main_name
-------------------------------------------------
 1      10     20.2    x        T       abc
 2      22     11      y        T       abc
 3      12.1   15      z        F       abc
```

I want to update `table1` with the values for that start and end which are `pending` from `table1` with the respective values from `table2` for same start and end.

This is just an example, I have 100k+ records in table1.

I wrote an update query:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.value = t2.value 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.start = t2.start AND t1.end = t2.end 
               AND t2.value NOT LIKE 'pending'
               AND t1.value LIKE 'pending' 
WHERE t1.main_name = 'abc' 
  AND t2.main_name = 'abc'
```

But this is taking a lot of time! It's updating only 3-4 rows per second!
And I have 100k+ rows to update.

Is there any other way/query optimization to bring down the time?

*Note:The table contains other main_name values too other than 'abc'

Comment: A more detailed answer can be found here https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47134/updating-a-table-efficiently-using-join

Comment: And how fast does that join run when you do it as a select? If it is quick, and If this is a one off operation, you could consider making a new table from the results of the select, dump the original table and rename the new one to take its place

Comment: @CaiusJard Not a good option, as for every main_name i can't create another tables

Comment: Didn't answer my question as to performance of the straight select

Comment: Please use **internationally known** units - thousands, millions, billions .....

Answer (score 0):

**cursor** is better option, please read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21148988/7942868. as you can see when you use update SQL will create a transaction over DB and so it makes overhead.